# EnEncodeNameReplacements is not working in sitecore

Tags: url, sitecore, urlencode

When I create new page with the name containing spaces for eg: **My Page** in sitecore cm and try to navigate to that page in the browser the space is replaced by %20 like this **My%20Page**.
I have even added the EncodeNameReplacements in sitecore.config for replacing whitespace with - but its still not working. Someone please give a solution for this.

Comment: %20 is encoded space. It's not a bug...

Comment: `%20` is basically the encoded version of `space`. so whenever you have a space like `im good`, it will replace the space with `%20` like `im%20good`. Its already made like that

Comment: @MarekMusielak i know its not a bug but for better readability I want to replace the %20 with a  dash(-), is there any way for this to be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very first thing is, we have to make our page URL SEO friendly. So, in Sitecore, we have the freedom to create an item with a name to be used as URL and DisplayName for human understanding. So, I would advise you that you should create pages with a naming convention like 'my-page' or 'contact-us' and set the Display name for that page.

So, using the above approach your URLs will be neat and clean, and SEO friendly.